# Accessing UIButtons in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I created a custom UITableViewCell subclass in IB.  I have 3 buttons that I'd like to reset their selected state.  I thought I could do something like this, but it's not working.  The subview is never a type of UIButton class.  Am I approaching this problem correct?  Am I looping through the correct property of UITableViewCell?  I see in the debugger, there is my cell variable, and then beneath it and slightly indented, I see UITableViewCell, and my 3 buttons.  But I am not sure how to get a reference to those buttons.  Thanks.

```
NSIndexPath *conditionPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]; 
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.FilterSortVC.TableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:conditionPath];

for (UIView *subview in cell.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton *aButton = (UIButton *)subview;
        aButton.selected = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a tag for each one of these buttons, declare a constant for each to have more readable code, and then use [`viewWithTag:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW26) to obtain the view from the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I think Items in a cell are stored in the `contentView`.
try this:

```
for (UIView *subview in cell.contentView.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton *aButton = (UIButton *)subview;
        aButton.selected = NO;
    }
}
```